# SWARM .ETH help

Tags: swarm, ens

I got 3dhdwallpapers.eth name and set content resolve to a swarm hash 4197442eceb1c1d4a0c7af21e17cb48e990a07ba2d6f72d7e9c09efd172279cc

and I run command

publicResolver.setContent(namehash('3dhdwallpapers.eth'), '0x4197442eceb1c1d4a0c7af21e17cb48e990a07ba2d6f72d7e9c09efd172279cc', {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 100000});

Now txn fine in etherscan
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x50f225487cc5cd1d34ecbf07eba83f64af8604d12b7c9db4914ed016ef10bcdb

when I check http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/3dhdwallpapers.eth/ getting error- error resolving 3dhdwallpapers.eth: '3dhdwallpapers.eth' is not a content hash

Why 0x4197442eceb1c1d4a0c7af21e17cb48e990a07ba2d6f72d7e9c09efd172279cc is not a content has when I can see hash data in http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/4197442eceb1c1d4a0c7af21e17cb48e990a07ba2d6f72d7e9c09efd172279cc/ ?

but getContent('3dhdwallpapers.eth') giving "0x4197442eceb1c1d4a0c7af21e17cb48e990a07ba2d6f72d7e9c09efd172279cc"

Is that 0x giving problem? But as per  http://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html I need to add 0x with hash. Please help.

--------------------- updated-----------------------

Okay if swam gateway running test node. I run swarm in my main net

and new has is 
9af7f4a3d9548f37b0c6e391fa8b1e23a6895e31d2eecc60c88dfd67a8c3eef4

it open as http://80.241.221.232:8500/bzz:/9af7f4a3d9548f37b0c6e391fa8b1e23a6895e31d2eecc60c88dfd67a8c3eef4/

File and I resolve content hash using publicResolver.setContent(namehash('3dhdwallpapers.eth'), '0x9af7f4a3d9548f37b0c6e391fa8b1e23a6895e31d2eecc60c88dfd67a8c3eef4', {from: eth.accounts[0], gas: 100000})

txn pass through- https://etherscan.io/tx/0xac2f357f5d5a78ceaec407da4fe51db33f31ec21c62d35d938c9e4c193c40c90

and getContent('3dhdwallpapers.eth') gives correct hash "0x9af7f4a3d9548f37b0c6e391fa8b1e23a6895e31d2eecc60c88dfd67a8c3eef4"

Still getting error in http://80.241.221.232:8500/bzz:/3dhdwallpapers.eth/
as 'error resolving 3dhdwallpapers.eth: no contract code at given address'

Any help here much appreciated..

Comment: swarm-gateways uses Ropsten for ENS resolution. This will be changed once the ENS soft launch period is over... so in a week or two.

Answer (score 1):

**What's working correctly?**

When you first tried, Swarm was not yet integrated with ENS on Mainnet. It is now, and correctly looks up the most recently posted content hash: `0x9af7f4a3d9548f37b0c6e391fa8b1e23a6895e31d2eecc60c88dfd67a8c3eef4`.

The gateway at http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/3dhdwallpapers.eth is correctly looking up the hash at the ENS name, and delivering the content with that hash.

**So why is the page blank when I visit the link?**

If you view the source on the page you will see the content of the index HTML page you uploaded. That page is trying and failing to load several other scripts.

**How do I make the other files accessible to my html?**

[Upload a directory of files](https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#manifests), recursively. It should contain your HTML page, and any other JavaScript, CSS, etc assets you want. The upload looks something like:

```
$ swarm --recursive --defaultpath wallpaper-root/index.html --bzzapi http://swarm-gateways.net/ up wallpaper-root/ 2> up.log
0x24691fdc32b6feb77babdd1d78d822a030198a5163edc9214e219a6666c544a7
```

This creates a manifest that Swarm uses to look up paths to files on your site. Swarm will give you a new hash to that manifest, which you can set your ENS name to point at.

Answer (score 0):

Now Swarm integrated with ENS on Mainnet and http://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/3dhdwallpapers.eth works fine.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Once you have 50 reputation you will be able to comment on the question.

Comment: Please explain more how you solved your own problem. Thanks